# Как правильно менять шрифты в отправленном боте сообщении

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь поменять шрифт отправленного ботом сообщения с помощью MarkdownV2, выходит ошибка об отсутствии исключения "."

```
start_message = '''
Приветствую. Для дальнейшей работы необходимо завести __"личный кабинет"__'''
MESSAGES = {
    'start': start_message
}


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, MESSAGES['start'], parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Ошибка: aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantParseEntities: Can't parse entities: character '.' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас возникает такая ошибка, потому что символ `.` зарезервирован. Вы можете просто его убрать или добавьте `\\` перед `.`, тем самым экранируете.

Comment: @OverLord если вам помог ответ, пожалуйста, оцените его голосом.